# My SQL Keeps Getting Deleted

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have 15 saved queries that filter data from a master table. They just filter out different values (Location Code ie, LAX, NYC, CHI etc).

My problem is that the SQL statements of those queries occasionally get changed to just `SELECT;`

When I re-enter the SQL and save, it will be fine again. But later it may get changed again back to just `SELECT;`

The problem is intermittent and does not affect the same query every time.  I can't pinpoint why this is happening.

So my question is how does this happen and how can I prevent it?

I'm using Windows 7 with Access 2013

Comment: I've never seen what you described.  Is your database shared with other users who have an opportunity to alter the saved queries?

Comment: I know right! So frustrating... I have one DB on a shared drive in which others have access to (but no one else in my department uses access), and I also have an identical one on my personal drive. Same issue with both.

Comment: I've seen it mentioned before, e.g., [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/disappearing-queries-t1130420.html), but it seems to be an infrequent and elusive critter.

Comment: @JoeFerrer Check your database "Track name AutoCorrect info" setting.  If it is enabled (checked), disable it and see whether that change stops the queries from being altered without your knowledge.  That is a long shot guess, but I got nothing better to offer.

Comment: Thanks @HansUp I'll give it a shot. It's worth a try!

Comment: Did a test run and it seems to work so far. I'll try again later and see if it holds up. Thanks so much everyone, I'll let you know if they disappear  again!

Comment: @JoeFerrer I'm curious whether you've seen the problem again after disabling *Track name AutoCorrect*.  Please update us whenever you can.  Thanks.

Comment: @HansUp, it's been a few months and the problem has not been duplicated! Looks like Track name AutoCorrect did the trick.  Thanks everyone!